# Create a simple pure Pascal-only text editor on Linux

Tags: editor, pascal

All right ? I'm wanting to create a simple text editor only in pure Pascal on Linux, simply so that I can open a file and edit it within the program itself, or create one within it and do the rest already mentioned. What I got so far is the following:

In this code below I create a file, then I add the text I want to it without exiting the program and I only exit with CTRL-Z, but there is no interaction of the directional arrows to be able to edit the file as needed:

```
program textos;
uses crt;

var
  file_name: string;
  f: text;
  c: char;
  s: string;
begin
  writeln('Enter the name of the file to create');
  readln(file_name);
  writeln('Enter your text to be recorded in the file ', file_name);
  writeln('End with CTRL-Z followed by ENTER');writeln;
  assign(f, file_name);
  rewrite(f);
  repeat;
    read(c);
    write(f,c);
  until c=#26; {is equivalent to chr(26), which is CTRL-Z}
  close(f);
  writeln('Now look at the file ', file_name, ' in your directory');
  writeln;
  writeln('Reading now from disk line by line and putting on screen:');
  reset(f); {opening for reading}
  while (not eof(f)) do
    begin
      readln(f,s);
      writeln(s);
    end;
end.
```

And I already searched but I didn't find anything related and I only left it to come here in the last case. If anyone can help I would appreciate it, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

While your terminal is in cooked mode it interprets any control characters for you.
Thus pressing Control‑Z emits a [`SIGTSTP`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) by default stopping your application.
Similarly, pressing arrow keys are intercepted and handled by your terminal, too.
Therefore you cannot check for `char` values.

You will first need to switch to the raw [terminal mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_mode).
This allows you to check for keystrokes as they occur, but you’ll also need to take care of other things.

Usually you delegate this task to a library such as `ncurses`, because you don’t wanna be troubled by such low-level stuff like interfacing with, for example, [`agetty(8)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/agetty.8.html) or `xterm(1)`.
Hence I refer you to using a library, too.